# MVC4: model backing the 'SisContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migration to update database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, membership-provider

I asked this question before as well but I'm posting it again, hoping may b i can get help
Here it goes

When I try to Login with details that are available in database(SIS) I get this error.

```
The model backing the 'SisContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database. Thing is Database(SIS) was manually added using add existing item and not generated automatically and when I click on show all files button on solution explorer after running application, i get new database called`ASPNETDB.mdf`
```

My SisContext looks like this

```
public class SisContext : DbContext
    {
        //protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        //{
        //    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IncludeMetadataConvention>();
        //}
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BusinessUnit> BusinessUnits { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LicenseHolder> LicenseHolders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<License> Licenses { get; set; }

        public SisContext():base("SIS")
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<SisContext>(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have another class called `DataContextInitializer` which looks like this

```
public class DataContextInitializer:DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SisContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(SisContext context)
        {
        WebSecurity.Register("Demo", "123456", "demo@demo.com", true, "Demo", "Demo");
        Roles.CreateRole("Admin");
        Roles.AddUserToRole("Demo", "Admin");
        }
    }
```

In my AccountController the Login method is as follows;

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
    {

        //
        // GET: /Account/
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            if(Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

`ValidateUser` method that is being used in above `Login` action is in class `CodeFirstMembershipProvider` class which inherits from `MembershipProvider`

```
 public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                return false;
            }
            using (SisContext Context = new SisContext())
            {
                AspNetUser User = null;
                User = Context.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(Usr => Usr.Username == username);//error mentioned above is shown here
                if (User == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (!User.IsApproved)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (User.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                String HashedPassword = User.Password;
                Boolean VerificationSucceeded = (HashedPassword != null && Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(HashedPassword, password));
                if (VerificationSucceeded)
                {
                    User.PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess = 0;
                    User.LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    User.LastActivityDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                }
                else
                {
                    int Failures = User.PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess;
                    if (Failures < MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts)
                    {
                        User.PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess += 1;
                        User.LastPasswordFailureDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    }
                    else if (Failures >= MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts)
                    {
                        User.LastPasswordFailureDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        User.LastLockoutDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        User.IsLockedOut = true;
                    }
                }
                Context.SaveChanges();
                if (VerificationSucceeded)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

in my web config I have added my custommembershipProvider

```
 <membership defaultProvider="CodeFirstMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CodeFirstMembershipProvider" type="Sorama.CustomAuthentication.CodeFirstMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SisContext" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CodeFirstRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CodeFirstRoleProvider" type="Sorama.CustomAuthentication.CodeFirstRoleProvider" connectionStringName="SisContext" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <!--<httpModules>
      <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </httpModules>-->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="180" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SISContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\SIS.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Did you run add-migration and update-database

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of public class DataContextInitializer:DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SisContext>? Why did you decide to seed data using this method rather than through migrations?